# Xcode 6 Navigation Bar Constraints Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am currently working on a basic app that has many single view view controllers. I am trying to add a navigation bar to one of my view controllers, when using the "Suggested Constraints", I can see nothing. When the only restraint on the Navigation bar is a center horizontal, it shows up but I think it is too long for the screen. When I tried to add a button on the left side of the Navigation bar, it would not show up in my app because the navigation bar does not have the correct width. I know I have the wrong constraint setup, please help.

Comment: Have you try Editor --> Embed in Navigation Controller

Comment: Thank you! Editor -- Embed in Navigation Controller worked, but do I need a navigation controller for every View Controller?

Comment: No, you only need one.

Comment: But how do you achieve this if you don't want the additional navigation controller window!? In my case I want to place a UICollectionView which has the UINavigationBar at the top, which will sit in a ContainerView for a slide menu. So I don't want the entire Navigation Controller by embedding the navigation Controller?!